# How to display a text after a choice is selected in google form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

So I have my drop down connected to spreadsheet. There are two column which is ID and Name. In my google form, I want the user to select the ID but not the name. The name should be shown according to the ID. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: provide more intel pls

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The alternative is to use another web app or to create your web form by using HTML/CSS/JavaScript (this could be done by using Google Apps Script).